# New to Python - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming and currently running through Al Sweigart's course on Udemy. I copied the code he was using for his elif example and I keep receiving the above error message - Can someone please explain why?..

Code and error below.

```
name = 'Bob'
age = '3000'
if name == 'Alice':
    print ('Hi Alice')
elif age < 12:
    print ('you are not Alice.')
elif age > 2000:
    print ('unlike you, ALice is no an undead, immortal vampire')
elif age > 100:
    print ('You are not Alice, Granny.')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\elif_example.py", line 5, in <module>
    elif age < 12:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

parse `age` to `int`: `age = 3000` or `age = int("3000")`

Comment: Wow that was a quick response and its has solved my issue. Thank you :)